# SQL Error: 17410, SQLState: 08000 ORACLE 11.2.0.1.10

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11.2.0.1.10 with hibernate but when I delete an object from UI, I am getting

> No more data to read from socket

I have tried by updating the ojbc.jar, Changed the server to shared, altered the session, changed the java.security file and also used c3po connections also.

Comment: found the answer. Issue is with the blob in the database, and once we corrected, the issue is gone. Please close the question.

Comment: How did you correct BLOB? Even I face the same issue in Oracle 12c with JDK 7.

Comment: changed the type to varchar2 or clob in navicat oracle.

Comment: If I understand correctly you changed the Blob to varchar2/CLOB?

Comment: yes thats right.